# How to fire same JQuery function on 2 different buttons?

Tags: jquery

I want to fire a JQuery function for 2 different buttons with a single selector. 
`$('.btn1 .btn2')` does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/);

```
$('.btn1, .btn2')
```

Answer (score 3):

you must use commas between them for example if you want to select 2 controls with ids: control1  and control2 the script would be:

```
$("#control1, #control2")
```

if you want to select 2 controls with 2 different classes you must write:

```
$(".class1, .class2")
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery selectors work almost exactly as your CSS selectors, which means you should seperate them with a comma. That means simply doing `$(".btn1, .btn2")` will work like you want it to.

If you want to read more about this particular method, theres a whole page about it on the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does - unless I have mistaken what you're asking

http://jsfiddle.net/GqhRA/

Answer (score -2):

if not possible to do above, try this

```
$(".button1, .button2").click(function(){
      //do
});
```